# read.table and read.csv skip the first column?

Tags: r

I have a file likes below:

```
> pageid,revid,user_rating
> 
> 1073624,16845228,Start

...
```

and I use:

```
data = read.csv (file_name)
```

then:

```
str(data)
```

then I have:

```
$ pageid                      : int  16845228
...
```

The pageid should start with '1073624', not '16845228'.

Also, I have the same file content, just instead of ',' is 'tab' character.

```
> pageid    revid   user_rating
> 
> 1073624   16845228    Start
```

and I use:

```
data = read.table (file_name, header = TRUE, sep = '\t')
```

And when I showed data, I have the same problem.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Basically, the read.table and read.csv in my case skip the first column (I guess that they see first column as row names, but I am not sure).

Comment: What does `rownames(data)` give?

Comment: post you csv file or upload it..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers. However I found the problem: there is a ',' redundant in the end of each line, so R misunderstood the data. Remove this character and everything is okay.